# Is it correct to say this?

Tags: grammar

> I write because that's the only thing left **to do**.

It sounds funny when you read the ending of the sentence out loud. I feel like it's more appropriate to say:

> I write because that's the only thing left **doing**.

What's the correct way to say it?

Comment: It's unclear what your context is, and that would affect the meaning a lot, but your first sentence is at least "more correct" than the second. "... the only thing left doing" is kind of meaningless gibberish.

Comment: Contrast "I have one call to make before I call it a day" with "I have one call making before I call it a day".

Answer (score 3):

Here's a context. An inmate in a prison is alone in his cell with only a notepad and a pen. If asked "Why are you writing?" he might answer,

> I write because that's the only thing left to do.

He could answer the question a little differently by saying,

> > I write because that's the only thing *worth* doing.

As to why *worth doing* is correct and *left doing* is incorrect, well, a true grammarian would need to step in here to explain why. I say this, because interestingly the following sentence--though worded differently--would be correct:

> When my partner took a sick day, I was *left doing* nothing.

I'll leave it at that!

Comment: Hi Don, shouldn't you put *worth* before doing in the second example?